# Can I Create an Account and Transfer Tokens in the same Transaction?

Tags: spl-token, web3.js, spl-token-program

Is it possible to create associated token account and transfer token to that token account at the same time in one transaction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make an ATA in one instruction, then use that created ATA in the next instruction, in a single transaction?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/is-it-possible-to-make-an-ata-in-one-instruction-then-use-that-created-ata-in-t)

Comment: Thanks @mikemaccana but this question has already been answered below!

Comment: As you note in you comment, the answer below doesn't show where 'associatedDestinationTokenAddr' comes from, whereas the answers to the question above do.

Comment: Gotcha. Well I was already familiar with the methods so I understood as soon as I saw the comment! But yes the other answer you mentioned is detailed. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

In Solana, a `transaction` is a list of instructions.

`allocating data` is an instruction, `token transfer` is an instruction etc...

In this case you need an

- associated token account instruction
- transfer token instruction

**example with @solana/web3.js**

```
let tx = new Transaction().add(

  // create nonce account
   Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        mintToken.associatedProgramId,
        mintToken.programId,
        mintPublicKey,
        associatedDestinationTokenAddr,
        destPublicKey,
        wallet.publicKey
      )


  // init nonce account
   Token.createTransferInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      associatedDestinationTokenAddr,
      wallet.publicKey,
      [],
      amount
    )
  );

  console.log(
    `txhash: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [feePayer, 
  nonceAccount])}`
);
```

You can find the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236211/how-to-transfer-custom-token-by-solana-web3-js)

Comment: What's the `associatedDestinationTokenAddr` defined as?